# Admin pages, edit notes of the title of posts and pages

Tags: pages, admin

Here is a screenshot of the admin console pages
I find here a description of the page on the title column (marked in RED), I would like to add such notes on pages I create or edit the ones already there.
I can't find it on the edit screen or any other related editable part.
Can anyone help me?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome!
Those areas you have marked with a red border is called **Post states**.

In order to modify post states you can use `display_post_states` filter.

The following example adds the post id to states.

````
function my_custom_display_post_states( $states, $post ) {
    // Add post id.
    $states['my_custom_state'] = $post->ID;

    return $states;
}

add_filter( 'display_post_states', 'my_custom_display_post_states', 10, 2 );```
````

Please check [WordPress documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/display_post_states/) for more information.